# Window.onbeforeunload = null not working

Tags: javascript, session, timeout, onbeforeunload

I'm adding `window.onbeforeunload = null` in the session timeout JavaScript.

It works but when we `minify` the scripts it does not work anymore every time the session times out it keeps showing the leave or stay dialog box.

Comment: Ok. That sounds bad. Oh...was there a question in there someplace?

Comment: What's _the session time javascript_? How do you add the event listener to `onbeforeunload`? Some code would definitely help.

Comment: This is the code window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { var msg = "samplemsg"; return msg }

Comment: The session time out code is from bootstrap session timeout and it is working while minified

Comment: The other question out there is about onbeforeunload not working not the minification issue

Comment: Its not working on ie only tho